# How to check two numbers and skip after two numbers

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to check two numbers and skip after two numbers like
1,2 and skip 3,4 display 5,6 and skip 7,8 and so on..

```
        {% set side = 'right' %}
        {% if (loop.index condition) %}
            {% set side = 'left' %}
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: maintain a counter, increment in loop and reset to 0 if it reaches 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (loop.index % 4 == 1 || loop.index % 4 == 2) { } //1,2,5,6...
else { } //3,4,7,8...
```

Comment: clever stuff,  I always forget modulus

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [cycle](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html) function.
Where `foo` is your collection, or replace with a plain number.

```
{% set loop_Length = foo|length %}

{% for i in 0..loop_Length %} 
    <div class="{{ cycle(['right', 'right', 'left', 'left'], i) }}">

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or to do it based on the loop counter

```
{% for foo in fubar %} 
    <div class="{{ cycle(['right', 'right', 'left', 'left'], loop.index) }}">

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below:

```
<div class="{{ cycle(['left', 'right'], loop.index % 4 == 1 || loop.index % 4 == 2 ? 0 : 1) }}" >
```